# xcode 6 swift system() command

Tags: macos, swift

Is there a good description of swift system command? For example, this code

```
    let x = system("ls -l `which which`")
    println(x)
```

produces 
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  14496 Aug 30 04:29 /usr/bin/which

**0**

I would like to separate the output from **the return code**

Answer (score 9):

`system()` is not a Swift command but a BSD library function. You get the documentation
with ["man system"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/system.3.html) in a Terminal Window:

> The system() function hands the argument command to the command
>   interpreter sh(1).  The calling process
>        waits for the shell to finish executing the command, ignoring SIGINT and SIGQUIT, and blocking SIGCHLD.

The output of the "ls" command is just written to the standard output and not to any
Swift variable.

If you need more control then you have to use `NSTask` from the Foundation framework.
Here is a simple example:

```
let task = NSTask()
task.launchPath = "/bin/sh"
task.arguments = ["-c", "ls -l `which which`"]

let pipe = NSPipe()
task.standardOutput = pipe
task.launch()

let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
if let output = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
    println(output)
}

task.waitUntilExit()
let status = task.terminationStatus
println(status)
```

Executing the command via the shell "/bin/sh -c command ..." is necessary here because
of the "back tick" argument. Generally, it is better to invoke the commands directly,
for example:

```
task.launchPath = "/bin/ls"
task.arguments = ["-l", "/tmp"]
```

Comment: If system is not a Swift command, how come in runs from Swift? This is not capricious comment, it is a question on Swift's semantics.The code you present of corse works - I had tried it before. I was just wondering why I could not/should not use system() instead. If you note in my "code, variable x IS assigned the output of both ls and $?

Comment: @LannyRosicky: All (well, most) library functions are available to Swift as part of the Darwin module which is included e.g. by Foundation.

Comment: BTW, the example code gives "Bound value in a conditional binding mut bo of Optional type "

Comment: @LannyRosicky:  Try `println("x=\(x)")` to convince yourself that `x` is only assigned the exit code. The output of the command is written directly to the console. – I have (again) tested the above code with Xcode 6.1 GM Seed 2 where it compiles and runs as expected.

Comment: Yes. x does contain only $?. Your example works in my version 6.0 (6A279r) only if I forgo the "if" .  I will upgrade it. And I will read on Darwin module to stop myself from putting my foot in ...

Comment: @LannyRosicky: I have tested the code again with the current Xcode 6.1. Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: FYI, 'NSTask' has been renamed to 'Process' now.